How to we represent the charge on an ion?
While writing the charge on an ion, do we write it as A⁻² or as A²⁻, my teacher uses the former, so is that the correct way or does it make no difference.

And if an atomic ion, there are no stable doubly-negative atomic ions known. They all auto-ionize back to singly-negative, and not all atoms have stable singly-negative ions (e.g. noble gases).

IUPAC's Red Book, rule IR-4.3 INDICATION OF IONIC CHARGE outlines

Ionic charge is indicated by means of a right upper index, as in $\ce{A^{n+}}$ or $\ce{A^{n-}}$ (not $\ce{A^{+n}}$ or $\ce{A^{-n}}$). If the formula is placed in enclosing marks, the right upper index is placed outside the enclosing marks. For polymeric ions, the charge of a single repeating unit should be placed inside the parentheses that comprise the polymeric structure or the total charge of the polymeric species should be placed outside the polymer parentheses.

Among the examples which follow, e.g. $\ce{Cu^+}$, $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$, $\ce{[Al(OH2)6]^{3+}}$.
Beside forms like $\ce{A^{-2}}$ which are not (i.e. no longer) recommended by IUPAC, you occasionally find something like $\ce{Mg^{++}}$ (instead of $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ in elder literature.  In newly written reports, this form shouldn't be used either.
Don't use bold characters to depict elements, and note that radical (today) in chemistry refers to the presence of (at least one) "unpaired electron", a property independent of presence/absence of charge (see the most recent post about this here).
Connelly, N. G.; Damhus, T.; Hartshorn, R. M.; Hutton, A. T. (eds.) Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations 2005, RSC publishing, 2005.  The free reprint is available here, this and other Color Books by IUPAC are introduced briefly ion the nomenclature section of the resources page of chemistry.stackexchange.
